# Elliptic curve point addition over a finite field in Python

Tags: python, math, cryptography, elliptic-curve

In short, Im trying to add two points on an elliptic curve y^2 = x^3 + ax + b over a finite field Fp. I already have a working implementation over R, but do not know how to alter the general formulas Ive found in order for them to sustain addition over Fp.

When P does not equal Q, and Z is the sum of P and Q:

```
        dydx = (Q.y - P.y)/(Q.x - P.x)
        Z.x = dydx**2 - P.x - Q.x
        Z.y = dydx * (Z.x - P.x) + P.y
```

When P equals Q, again with Z as the sum:

```
        dydx = (3 * (P.x)**2 + self.a)/(2 * P.y)
        Z.x = dydx**2 - 2 * P.x
        Z.y = dydx * (Z.x - P.x) + P.y
```

These are the same formules as found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_addition). What needs to be modified?

Clarification: The code above works for elliptic curves over R. I am looking to find what needs to be changed for it to work for addition of points over a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Finite_fields) of order p.

Comment: Are you referring to Fp as the finite field F in mod P?

Comment: @rocky Point addition over a finite field differs from that over R, and yes, P, Q, Z are a Point class with the attributes x, y. I dont know how to account for this difference.

Comment: Will you only be doubling points, or will you be adding to separate points? An important thing to do would be to calculate inverses mod P.

Comment: @RobFoley Both, with a distinction made in the code. I have found some information around but I couldnt get to a working solution.

Comment: It's been some time since I did cryptography, so I can't really give a proper answer. I would highly recommend reading up on Galois Field arithmetic, as Galois was the founder of finite field math.

Comment: In that regard, there is extensive literature about doing arithmetic in a field of p^n points.

Comment: From what I gather, as the comment chain clarifies, he wants to know how to apply the point additions above to a finite field mod P.

Comment: Additions in the high-level sense, not in terms of the other additions that are using to implement the addition.  There are other operations as well: subtract, multiply and divide, exponentate.  You're more likely to get folks to help you if the question states the problem without having to wade through comments to get clarification.

Comment: Hint: You're operating in a finite field, so you need some modulo operations (or use of `pow(b,e,n)`). Division like means extended euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Ive tried using %p in various places but the result of the addition came out all wrong. Where should I place them specifically?

Comment: @ArtjomB.: No need for the extended Euclidean algorithm to do division: `pow(a, p-2, p)` gives the inverse of `a` modulo `p` efficiently (assuming that `a` is invertible, of course).

Comment: @Raylan: do you already have a Python class representing objects of the finite field F_p?  If not, then the first step is probably to either write such a class, or (better) find an existing implementation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.  First is that you have the wrong formulas: those are the formulas for the *negation* of the sum, or equivalently the third point of the curve that lies on the line through P and Q.  Compare with the formula you linked to on Wikipedia, and you'll see that what you have for `Z.y` is the negation of the value they have.

A second issue is that your formulas don't take the origin into account: if P is the inverse of Q in the group law, then P + Q will be the origin, which doesn't lie on the affine part of the curve and so can't be described as a pair of `(x, y)` coordinates.  So you'll need some way to specify the origin.

Let's write some code.  First we need a representation for the points on the curve.  We use the string `'Origin'` to represent the origin, and a simple named tuple for the points on the affine part of the elliptic curve.

```
# Create a simple Point class to represent the affine points.
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple("Point", "x y")

# The point at infinity (origin for the group law).
O = 'Origin'
```

For demonstration purposes, we choose a particular elliptic curve and prime.  The prime should be greater than `3` for the addition formulas to be valid.  We also write a function that we can use to check that a particular point is a valid representation of a point on the curve.  This will be useful in checking that we didn't make any mistakes in implementing the addition formulas.

```
# Choose a particular curve and prime.  We assume that p > 3.
p = 15733
a = 1
b = 3

def valid(P):
    """
    Determine whether we have a valid representation of a point
    on our curve.  We assume that the x and y coordinates
    are always reduced modulo p, so that we can compare
    two points for equality with a simple ==.
    """
    if P == O:
        return True
    else:
        return (
            (P.y**2 - (P.x**3 + a*P.x + b)) % p == 0 and
            0 <= P.x < p and 0 <= P.y < p)
```

To do divisions modulo `p` you'll need some way to compute inverses modulo `p`.  A simple and reasonably efficient trick here is to use Python's three-argument variant of the `pow` function: by Fermat's Little Theorem, `pow(a, p-2, p)` will give an inverse of `a` modulo `p` (provided of course that that inverse exists - that is, that `a` is not divisible by `p`).

```
def inv_mod_p(x):
    """
    Compute an inverse for x modulo p, assuming that x
    is not divisible by p.
    """
    if x % p == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError("Impossible inverse")
    return pow(x, p-2, p)
```

And finally, here are the two functions to compute negation and addition on the elliptic curve.  The addition function is based directly on the formulas you gave (after correcting the sign of `Z.y`), makes use of `inv_mod_p` to perform the divisions modulo `p`, and does a final reduction modulo `p` for the computed `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
def ec_inv(P):
    """
    Inverse of the point P on the elliptic curve y^2 = x^3 + ax + b.
    """
    if P == O:
        return P
    return Point(P.x, (-P.y)%p)

def ec_add(P, Q):
    """
    Sum of the points P and Q on the elliptic curve y^2 = x^3 + ax + b.
    """
    if not (valid(P) and valid(Q)):
        raise ValueError("Invalid inputs")

    # Deal with the special cases where either P, Q, or P + Q is
    # the origin.
    if P == O:
        result = Q
    elif Q == O:
        result = P
    elif Q == ec_inv(P):
        result = O
    else:
        # Cases not involving the origin.
        if P == Q:
            dydx = (3 * P.x**2 + a) * inv_mod_p(2 * P.y)
        else:
            dydx = (Q.y - P.y) * inv_mod_p(Q.x - P.x)
        x = (dydx**2 - P.x - Q.x) % p
        y = (dydx * (P.x - x) - P.y) % p
        result = Point(x, y)

    # The above computations *should* have given us another point
    # on the curve.
    assert valid(result)
    return result
```

We can check the code above by creating a handful of points on the curve and checking that they obey the expected arithmetic laws.

```
P = Point(6, 15)
Q = Point(8, 1267)
R = Point(2, 3103)
TwoP = ec_add(P, P)
ThreeP = ec_add(TwoP, P)
# Compute 4P two different ways.
assert ec_add(P, ThreeP) == ec_add(TwoP, TwoP)
# Check the associative law.
assert ec_add(P, ec_add(Q, R)) == ec_add(ec_add(P, Q), R)
```

Comment: I missed your comment on my post cause it was marked as read by the Android app, sorry. Your answer did fill in all the missing gaps in my knowledge, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for reference pure python implementation of secp256k1, secp256r1 and ed25519 available at https://github.com/user8547/fast-ecc-python.