# Elliptic curve double and add implementation in python

Tags: python, multiplication, elliptic-curve

I am trying to implement the "double and add" algorithm to quickly multiply points on an elliptic curve in Python (3, please).

Based off this previous answer (about addition and doubling),

[Elliptic curve point addition over a finite field in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074172/elliptic-curve-point-addition-over-a-finite-field-in-python)

the Wikipedia page,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication

and my textbook (Information Security, by Mark Stamp), I came up with the following code:

```
def point_add(N_x, N_y, Q_x, Q_y, p):
    m = (Q_y - N_y) * pow((Q_x-N_x), p-2, p)
    ret_x = (m ** 2 - N_x - Q_x) % p
    ret_y = (m*(N_x - ret_x) - N_y) % p
    return ret_x, ret_y


def point_double(N_x, N_y, a, p):
    m = (3*(N_x ** 2)+a) * pow(2*N_y, p-2, p)   
    ret_x = (m ** 2 - N_x - Q_x) % p
    ret_y = (m*(N_x - ret_x) - N_y) % p
    return ret_x, ret_y


multiplier_A = 44
multiplier_B = 57
a = 10
b = -21
p = 41
N_x = 3
N_y = 6
Q_x = 0
Q_y = 0

multiplier_A = list(bin(multiplier_A)[2:])
multiplier_B = list(bin(multiplier_B)[2:])

for x_a in multiplier_A:
    if x_a == '1':
        Q_x, Q_y = point_add(N_x, N_y, Q_x, Q_y, p)
    N_x, N_y = point_double(N_x, N_y, a, p)

print(Q_x, Q_y)
```

Which sure enough returns a wrong result.

Where do I go wrong? A new implementation from scratch is also more than welcome.

**UPDATE**

I want to multiply the point (3,6) times `multiplier_A` and `multiplier_B`. For now I'm trying to only do `multiplier_A(3,6)`.

`a`, `b`, and `p` are the elliptic curve paramethers

Comment: How do you know it returns a wrong result?

Comment: Very good question. I checked here http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/elliptic/index, assuming the result was gonna be correct. However it seems every online resource I find gives me different results

Answer (score 0):

Both of your functions are totally correct, except small typo that `point_double()` should have `N_x` instead of `Q_x` inside its body, because there is no `Q_x` argument in function (`Q_x` is undefined).

I checked them against my own implementation that I used many times in different algorithms, my implementation is called `add_dbl()` in code below.

You can see below that I used standard [Secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) elliptic curve, that is default curve for BitCoin.

Function `test()` generates 200 random points and does addition and doubling with both my and yours implementations, and checks if they give equal results.

Code doesn't have any non-standard dependecies, just imports standard [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVXbbqNIEH33V/RqNRpwfGnaXEfyAxfziBLtvo1WLYg7CUoMDJA1fH2mqhswTmZXo9EgJS6qzqk63V1dVH37VBY7t6rf3o7igTyKlveavyLBiiQr0ulfFgSetGlE3ZKEfCIm2e/JDqIy0DOyJx1ZLsmO3BCfLOHlhgQqBqGqPGs9WxEtAbehk@2WmMDVJSB/UPEVYegjf@wx3yeSqKL41KJ9rQuSlIVYzN77xQLVpscjP2YvqBfE3nbwB8nuOiiMDDD7wRzWARUhmjfSR9LiiIjh9VL0rhuYKuPIvO1w6cBH3m0vX/oLqwGCpgFoSeQ/uSE6GLhGgC9xlWsDV6rjIiVRvDTiQ4qerCHzRO3wtfvIxWVqDaAaAAyoS7QfoyoBRADUX@LDTkLeYTOztBG8KvOi1Ybd@pM8tW3VfNluRbHJ8vYegpu83Z7z53z7l7ivmGU/G@@g5/N504j7x01ZP27BYOt/2aY6PkiYD6KotAKwHGkl6Ovi4eG/YhyUEbJ42hjaOV5wsG0HYl4UBoEfcsvyqc08i4cH16EBdThlXhCHUcBZFB6YG3nc8mLmGlbADTt2Dcdzp82knenu/Mh3HM5sfxeatsWtyDdjyMDpwTCo67s8jgwnME2X@7ZrWabhcS80nYi6IDYwaGQGKuO3n1z1gQe@fwB1Nvdj0/XpLuBBHDHr4IY8ojvbNExjfqCXuzudrDxUDpdFSzh4E46XBK07tKrhtE/YMOCBPgHE2H3g6dZA0wG4Zogei3HZfye8@0xyZAdy2YLVBJJteFpqKixp@lhhhkPlMrhSrLnwY/mavYiZ9vSd6J1Kj0L0m3RUzpYSPKgG7P8KT36r8FY00y3KT1UJs7OGqVGepKfKIPf8uqm7MR7ckuPgzKTzoaxJjtlIXmCKR6ExSvXLyDg/5S@C/F2/zsaIvAMUOsCARF9V4Q3@qARyjKjMs6z6P1f8Hvi95H/4JEhqh1RNVXlHhVHZU5yqRdleBi0km7muxeKT1SJ9nryTgSM@BRnXox7r9rI2qtSv0Jn87Iwdf42cPj2zj9pQQZXIPiqAqv@pQL9CXSoPLTsW939Ud8i7V9TFAraN8yI9Cc7R@5nzU5oXnH9We6VaavH29h0)

```py
def get_y(A, B, N, x):
    assert N % 4 == 3, N
    y2 = x ** 3 + A * x + B
    y = pow(y2, (N + 1) // 4, N)
    if pow(y, 2, N) != y2 % N:
        return None
    return y

def add_dbl(A, N, Px, Py, Qx = None, Qy = None):
    if Qx is None and Qy is None:
        Qx, Qy = Px, Py
    if Px == Qx and Py == Qy:
        s = ((Px * Px * 3 + A) * pow(Py * 2, -1, N)) % N
    else:
        s = ((Py - Qy) * pow(Px - Qx, -1, N)) % N
    x = (s * s - Px - Qx) % N
    y = (s * (Px - x) - Py) % N
    return x, y

def base_point():
    # https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1
    # https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf
    A = 0
    B = 7
    N = 0xFFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFE_FFFFFC2F
    x = 0x79BE667E_F9DCBBAC_55A06295_CE870B07_029BFCDB_2DCE28D9_59F2815B_16F81798
    y = 0x483ADA77_26A3C465_5DA4FBFC_0E1108A8_FD17B448_A6855419_9C47D08F_FB10D4B8
    q = 0xFFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFE_BAAEDCE6_AF48A03B_BFD25E8C_D0364141
    return A, B, N, x, y

def point_add(N_x, N_y, Q_x, Q_y, p):
    m = (Q_y - N_y) * pow((Q_x-N_x), p-2, p)
    ret_x = (m ** 2 - N_x - Q_x) % p
    ret_y = (m*(N_x - ret_x) - N_y) % p
    return ret_x, ret_y

def point_double(N_x, N_y, a, p):
    m = (3*(N_x ** 2)+a) * pow(2*N_y, p-2, p)   
    ret_x = (m ** 2 - N_x - N_x) % p
    ret_y = (m*(N_x - ret_x) - N_y) % p
    return ret_x, ret_y

def test():
    import random
    pb = base_point()
    A, B, N, *_ = pb
    for itest in range(200):
        while True:
            x0, x1 = [random.randrange(1, N) for i in range(2)]
            y0, y1 = [get_y(A, B, N, x) for x in (x0, x1)]
            if y0 is not None and y1 is not None:
                break
        
        add_a = add_dbl(A, N, x0, y0, x1, y1)
        add_b = point_add(x0, y0, x1, y1, N)
        assert add_a == add_b
        
        dbl_a = add_dbl(A, N, x0, y0)
        dbl_b = point_double(x0, y0, A, N)
        assert dbl_a == dbl_b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```